# Problems with Update and Table Inheritance with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I'm building an inheritance table schema like the following:

### Spec Code

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    discriminator = Column('type', String(50))
    updated = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    name = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class Engineer(Person):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'engineer'}
    start_date = Column(DateTime)

class Manager(Person):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'manager'}
    start_date = Column(DateTime)
```

### UPDATED (WORKING) CODE

```
import os
import sys

from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


try:
   os.remove('test.db')
except FileNotFoundError:
   pass 

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    discriminator = Column('type', String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    updated = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

class Engineer(People):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'engineer'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('people.id'), primary_key=True)
    kind = Column(String(100), nullable=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session()

e = Engineer()
e.name = 'Mike'
session.add(e)
session.flush()
session.commit()

# works when updating the object
e.name = "Doug"
session.add(e)
session.commit()


# works using the base class for the query
count = session.query(People).filter(
                           People.name.is_('Doug')).update({People.name: 'James'})

# fails when using the derived class
count = session.query(Engineer).filter(
                           Engineer.name.is_('James')).update({Engineer.name: 'Mary'})

session.commit()
print("Count: {}".format(count))
```

*Note: this is slightly modified example from [sql docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html)*

If I try to update the `name` for Engineer two things *should* happen.

1. update statement to the People table on column `name`
2. automatic trigger of update to the `updated` column on the People table

For now, i'd like to focus on number 1.  Things like the example below (as also documented in the full code example) will result in invalid SQL

```
session.query(Engineer).filter(
                           Engineer.name.is_('James')).update({Engineer.name: 'Mary'})
```

I believe the above generates the following:

> UPDATE engineer SET name=?, updated=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM people WHERE people.name IS ?

Again, this is invalid. The statement is trying to update rows in incorrect table.  `name` is in the base table.

I'm a little unclear about how inheritance tables *should* work but it seems like updates should work transparently with the derived object.  Meaning, when I update `Engineer.name` querying against the `Engineer` object SQLAlchemy should know to update the `People` table.  To complicate things a bit more, what happens if I try to update columns which exist in two tables

```
session.query(Engineer).filter(
                           Engineer.name.is_('James')).update({Engineer.name: 'Mary', Engineer.start_date: '1997-01-01'})
```

I suspect SQLAlchemy will not issue two update statements.

Comment: Why is it invalid? You're using single table inheritance, so `start_date` exists on the `people` table.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I wrote the example incorrectly.  Fixing now.  But `updated` exists only in parent class.

Comment: No, it generates `UPDATE people SET ...` because you're using single table inheritance.

Comment: Apologies to @univerio, I didn't correctly set up the example.  I've now updated the language and provided a working example of my problem

Comment: @quasiben did you ever get a resolution to this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @JamieBulln unfortunately no.  It's been some time since I posted this and didn't come back to it

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, the update statement disregards the joined inheritance and generates an update statement to what would be the "Engineer" table in your example. I'll post an issue on their tracker.